# linq to sql OnValidate() exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception

```
public partial class TeamworkSurvey
{
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (true)
            throw new ArgumentException("No matter what you enter is invalid");
    }
}
```

Simple enough. When this method return, it throw "ArgumentException was unhandled by user code".
What should I do?

Comment: Where did q1 come from? We would need to see more context to help.

Comment: @ReidEvans I just edited my code. OnValidate is a partial method defined in the linq to sql.

Comment: By the way, I do have any problem when publish to IIS. It did not raise a error event. It only come up when debug in VS.

Comment: Based on this code, when OnValidate is called the ArgumentException must be thrown because true == true.  You aren't logically doing a conditional.